# how to toggle a dynamic height div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic div which has content inside of it of different lengths. Rather than having a fixed height to slide down the content and having empty white space, I have created a dynamic script in JQuery which only slides down based on the how much content is in within the parent div.

I have managed to get the dynamic height to slide but I can't toggle it to slide back up.

```js
$(".parent_accordion").click(function() {
  const that = $(this);
  //console.log($(this).children().height());

  //let learning_accordion = $(this).parent().find(".my_learning_accordion_content").toggleClass("show-open");
  let learning_accordion = $(this).next();
  let inner_content = 0;

  learning_accordion.children().each(function() {
    inner_content += $(this).height();
    let me = that.next().css("height", inner_content + "px");
    me.toggle();
  });

  $(this).find("i").toggleClass("rotate");

});
```

```css
.my_learning_accordion_content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_learning_accordion_wrapper">
  <div class="learning_accordion">
    <div class="learning_accordion_wrap">
      <div class="parent_accordion flex-item space-between flex-v-center dark-blue-text">
        <div class="title">Completed</div>
        <i class="fa-light fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="my_learning_accordion_content dark-blue-text" style="height: 30px;">
        <div class="flex-item flex-v-center flex-h-center">
          <span>TOTAL:</span>
          <span class="cme_bold_text">&nbsp;10</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cme_tracker-parent">
          <div class="cme_tracker_wrap flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
            <div class="cme_credits">
              <span class="cme_bold_text"></span>
              <span class="credits_text font-weight-400">CE credits</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cme_activity_title_wrap">
              <div class="activity_type light-blue-text">touchTALKS</div>
              <div class="activity_title font-weight-400">test 3</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="learning_accordion_wrap">
      <div class="parent_accordion flex-item space-between flex-v-center dark-blue-text">
        <div class="title">In Progress</div>
        <i class="fa-light fa-chevron-down rotate"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="my_learning_accordion_content dark-blue-text" style="height: 111.781px;">
        <div class="cme_tracker-parent">
          <div>
            <div class="cme_tracker_wrap flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
              <div class="cme_credits grey-text">
                <span class="cme_bold_text"></span>
                <span class="credits_text font-weight-400">CE credits</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cme_activity_title_wrap">
                <div class="activity_type light-blue-text">touchEXPERT OPINIONS</div>
                <div class="activity_title font-weight-400">Chronic kidney disease in patients with type 2 diabetes</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="child_page_links flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
              <!-- <a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="#">Continue and complete test to claim credits</a> -->
              <a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="https://dev.touchneurology.com/education/test-2/ " target="_blank"> Continue and complete test to claim credits </a>
              <i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-long light-blue-text"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cme_tracker-parent">
          <div>
            <div class="cme_tracker_wrap flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
              <div class="cme_credits grey-text">
                <span class="cme_bold_text">1.5</span>
                <span class="credits_text font-weight-400">CE credits</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cme_activity_title_wrap">
                <div class="activity_type light-blue-text">touchIN CONVERSATION</div>
                <div class="activity_title font-weight-400">Achieving individualized glycemic targets in patients with type 2 diabetes</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="child_page_links flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
              <!-- <a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="#">Continue and complete test to claim credits</a> -->
              <a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="https://dev.touchneurology.com/cme/test/ " target="_blank"> Continue and complete test to claim credits </a>
              <i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-long light-blue-text"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="recommendations_and_user_settings">
        <!-- <div class="child_page_links flex-item space-between flex-v-center"><a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="#">Update your interests for relevant content</a><i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-long light-blue-text"></i></div> -->
        <div class="child_page_links flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
          <a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="/my-learning/saved-activities/">Saved activities</a>
          <i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-long light-blue-text"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="child_page_links flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
          <a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="/my-learning/saved-activities/">Your learning history</a>
          <i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-long light-blue-text"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="child_page_links flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
          <a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="/my-learning/subscriptions-interests/">Clinical Interests</a>
          <i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-long light-blue-text"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="child_page_links flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
          <a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="/my-learning/subscriptions-interests/">Communication Preferences</a>
          <i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-long light-blue-text"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="child_page_links flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
          <a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="/my-learning/notifications/">Notifications</a>
          <i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-long light-blue-text"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="child_page_links flex-item space-between flex-v-center">
          <a class="user_setting_links light-blue-text" href="/my-learning/account-settings/">Account settings</a>
          <i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-long light-blue-text"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [slideToggle](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).

Comment: @prettyInPink where in the code do I put that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up an example where content gets added via JS, you don't need to set any height on the elements. `slideToggle` will handle this.

You can set the animation speed and run a function once the animation has been completed.

```js
const acContent = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit vehicula sapien id, cras dictumst ultrices placerat suspendisse eros auctor arcu in magnis pellentesque, phasellus dis sociosqu lectus ridiculus pretium libero tempus penatibus. Condimentum sed etiam tristique vehicula conubia molestie cursus dictumst litora, curae enim vitae magnis eget vel placerat convallis rutrum, dignissim primis ligula quam mattis fermentum dictum natoque. Duis porttitor nulla bibendum nascetur in nam, nostra suspendisse sociosqu class nisi vulputate feugiat, tempor cursus odio eu ac.
Turpis feugiat porta lacus condimentum mi, euismod iaculis eleifend inceptos ad gravida, fusce cursus neque nec. Ultrices orci rhoncus mollis vehicula magnis posuere, diam a vitae viverra donec, erat dis venenatis nam per. Interdum pulvinar tortor taciti montes enim maecenas nec laoreet mus, eu felis consequat libero tincidunt nisl penatibus dis porttitor, eleifend sollicitudin ad odio posuere tristique curae varius.`;

const toggleSpeed = 1000;

const toggleAnimationFinished = function() {
  alert('Animation Finished');
}

$('.my_learning_accordion_content').text(acContent);

$(".parent_accordion").click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle(toggleSpeed, toggleAnimationFinished);
});
```

```css
.my_learning_accordion_content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="parent_accordion">Title</h3>
<div class="my_learning_accordion_content">Accordion content</div>
```